# How to check if last character in a string is 'space'?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a code as follows in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc92619/872VH/1/):

```
<span id="someid">check this phrase </span><br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Here I have placed a space after the word 'phrase', but when I put a conditional statement it always returns one result. How is it possible to check the end of the string for a space?

Comment: What do you mean by returns one results? What conditional statement are you talking about?

Comment: Check the fiddle I have posted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/872VH/3/ Another way: http://jsfiddle.net/872VH/5/

Comment: How did you get that regular expression?

Comment: I was finding random answers everywhere and wasn't sure of the correct regex. thank for the answers

Comment: If you want just a regular space as opposed to a newline/tab may as well just; `mystring.charAt(mystring.length - 1) === " "`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check whether the text value ends with space by the following regular-expression:

```
/\s$/
```

`/\s$/` means one space at the end of the string.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/872VH/2/)**

**JavaScript**

```
var mystring = $("#someid").text();

$("#someid").click( function (event) {
    if(/\s+$/.test(mystring)) {
        $("#result").text("space");    
    } else {
        $("#result").text("no space");

    }    
});
```

As **jfriend00** noticed `\s` does not means only space, it's white-space [i.e. includes tab too (\t)]

If you need only space use: `/ $/`.

Comment: You had previously posted the fiddle with `/\s+$/` as the regex, and that too works. What is the difference between this regex and `/\s+$/`?

Comment: `\s+` means one or more spaces, `\s` means a single space. You don't need more than one space at the end of the string to tell that your string ends with a space that's why the `+` is unnecessary.

Comment: Technically `\s` represents more than just a space.  If you want to check for JUST a space, then use `/ $/` with an actual space in the regex.

Comment: Yes, you're right it means white-space which can include tab too (\t).

Answer (score 8):

A more simple and clear solution would be using .endsWith()

```
"hallo ".endsWith(" "); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this way:-

```
/(.*)\s+$/
```

### JS:

```
var mystring = $("#someid").text();

$("#someid").click(function(event) {
    if(/(.*)\s+$/.test(mystring)) {
        $("#result").text("space");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#result").text("no space");    
    }
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/872VH/7/)**

Comment: What is the difference between `/(.*)\s+$/` regex and maybe another one like `/\s$/`? Since there are many alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `/%(?!$)/` checks against a percent sign that is not at the end of the string, not a space.

> How is it possible to check the end of the string for a space?

Use `/\s$`/.